# LaTeX exercises

Tags: best-practices, exercises, resources

Recently I've learning more about LaTeX and I would like to know where can I found exercises and documents to replicate in order to improve my skills.

Comment: I don't think there exists such a source of the sort you're looking for, partially because LaTeX is usually not taught as a formal course, so nobody has made any exercises. I think a lot of us have learned things simply by trying to answer questions on the site Even if you don't actually post your answer, it's a great learning experience to try to solve the problems and compare your solution to those posted by more experienced users.

Comment: not really quite as you describe but you could look at https://learnlatex.org which does have small examples and some exercises, but not really documents to replicate.

Comment: What OS are you using?